# Prior iOS 7 tintColor without navigationBar background

Tags: ios, objective-c, appearance

I'm setting:

```
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

In iOS 7 everything works ok - my `navigationController.navigationBar` is white (as I set it transparent) and all icons are colored to red. However in iOS 6 (where navigation bar is set NOT to be transparent) all icons are left with its original colors (eg blue). I can't find a way to color these images in iOS 6, is it possible?

To be more precise:

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    [self.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Now I get white navigation bar but also the titles and buttons are white - how to colour them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the documentation(s) carefully.

`UIWindow` inherits from `UIVIew` and the `tintColor` property of `UIView` is not available prior to iOS7. From the source itself (`UIView`):

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

It clearly defines this. So you cannot set this prior to iOS7.

You will have to set the `navigationBar`'s `tintColor` (which became `barTintColor` in iOS7) to white. You might want to use the `UIAppearance` selector for changes to be reflected throughout your app.

**EDIT**:

All items in a `UINavigationBar` are `UIBarButtonItem`s. You will have to set their own `tintColor`s.

Comment: I saw that it is only since iOS 7, thats why I've posted the question - maybe there was another way to do it earlier, without using tintColor. Anyway, setting navigationBar's tintColor to white makes buttons and titles white too, as I wrote in the question - how to colour them?